# Why does my drop-down menu differ from my profile?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign

In my drop-down menu, I got 212 as my reputation, but in my profile, it is recorded as 203. Is this a bug, or is this deliberate? What makes these reputation counts different?

Comment: Which menu is this? The one on the main site or the one here on meta?

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown counts are *net* changes, so the *net* reputation change for each time period listed.

The profile however lists all voting activity *in that time range*, so deleted votes (from those reversing their vote, or deleted users for example) won't show here...but their deletion *will* affect your net reputation, which the dropdown shows.

As an example: let's say you got a vote on Tuesday, then you later edited post someone didn't agree with on Thursday, so they take back their upvote.  On Thursday you now have a -10 *net* change, but really it's because it's as if that upvote *never happened*, because it was retracted, this is where the profile and popup can differ.

If this bothers you, up to once a day you can trigger a recalc of your reputation at the bottom of your reputation report, here: https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: What about this: Today, I've got 50 on my drop-down menu, but I really only have 40 in my profile. What's happening?